# Does microwaving move significantly more oil\fat from fries than other cooking method, how to prevent?

Tags: oil, microwave, fat

If I reheat originally fried fries, when I microwave fries or protein it seems to me a lot of fat in short time has leeched out\evaporated.  Does microwaving cause this and is there a way I can prevent it?

For fat to be removed I imagine the meat still has to reach the same temperature for fat\oil leeching as any other cooking method does.  Therefore perhaps Im using too much power and for too long and need to reduce those?  Or is there something about the way a microwave works that makes it quickly evaporate oils\fat from foods?

When reheating things like fries and protein, what might be a better cooking method so as not to loose fat\oil?

Comment: I find that the same thing happens when using an oven or toaster oven. I reheat fries, egg rolls, chicken, fish, (all fried) just to name a few. Without fail, more oil is released. I always look at it as a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

Oil / fat is slow to evaporate.  It is designed for high boiling and smoke point.  Yes you smell fat and it condenses on surfaces but if you leave a fryer on for 24 hours very little fat will evaporate.

Leaching is the process of extracting substances from a solid by dissolving them in a liquid.  There is no leaching going on heating fries in a microwave.

After a fry is cooled it will shrivel a bit and not hold as much fat but the fat is trapped (depending on the fat could even be in solid form).  When the fat melts some escapes. I know it is weird looking at the potato as a solvent but that is kind of what is going on here.

Microwave targets water molecules that do evaporate.  You may be sensing a less moisture as less fat.

Slow heating in the oven may have less fat loss.  I suggest if you heat to temp X you are going to have about the same fat loss.

If you really want fat then re-fry in fat to reheat.